# getbetween function not working?

Tags: php, function

I found this function on the internet and it doesn't seem to be working for some reason

```
function getbetween($content, $start, $end)
{
    $r = explode($start, $content);

    if (isset($r[1]))
    {
        $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
        return $r[0];
    }

    return '';
}
```

and it doesn't seem to be working, I tried it out on the following html file

```
<test>Hello</test>
```

and this is the php page which I tried to get the value hello with it

```
<?php

include('getbetween.php');
$str = getbetween('test.html','<test>','</test>');
echo $str;

?>
```

It doesn't seem to be working for some reason though in the past it has worked with me, does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: What debugging have you done? What's `$r` set to after the first explode? What is it set to after the second explode?

Comment: From your example you are trying to match content snippets on just a filename, not the file content.

Comment: I never getbetween...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a string to the function, not the actual contents of the file.  Try this to pass the actual html.

```
<?php

include('getbetween.php');
$str = getbetween(file_get_contents('test.html'),'<test>','</test>');
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find `<test>` or `</test>` from `"test.html"`. The *string*, not the *file*. Put the file's contents there or use `file_get_contents("test.html")`.

Comment: I'm trying to find what's between the two tags

Comment: Yeah, it's actually just the filename string issue.

Answer (score 0):

It does still work, however you seem to miss that the string

```
'test.html'
```

does not contain the start string nor the end string.

It is just a filename. PHP does not expand a string only it contains a file-name inside. So you might want to write yourself a function for that as well ;) No just joking that function exists already. An example:

```
include('getbetween.php');

$file = 'test.html';

$buffer  = file_get_contents($file);
$between = getbetween($buffer, '<test>', '</test>');

echo $between;
```

And then your function is not totally clear. Why not start from the beginning if start is not found?

```
function getbetween($content, $start, $end)
{
    $r = explode($start, $content, 2);

    if (isset($r[1]))
    {
        $r = explode($end, $r[1], 2);
    }

    return $r[0];
}
```

Otherwise return early:

```
function getbetween($content, $start, $end)
{
    $r = explode($start, $content, 2);

    if (!isset($r[1]))
    {
        return '';            
    }

    $r = explode($end, $r[1], 2);

    return $r[0];
}
```